# UTL Path Recognition

Tags: oracle12c, database-administration, system-administration

I have an existing code with UTL Path as "PathName"
I checked in Directories but it is not there with the" Pathname"
Need to know the path of the Directory using this filepath without DBA help

```
 SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_DIRECTORIES;
```

Existing codes

Need to know where the directory is created and need to know the path of the Directory with the server hosting it

Comment: maybe the directory object was not created or dropped. since the name is always specified as a string, you will only notice it at runtime

Comment: It is mapped and it is working currently. But need to know more about accessing and creating, mapping the path.